# Reading sprites from a NSMutableArray to detect collision

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision

I am adding sprites to a NSMutableArray like this:

```
        NSMutableArray * movableSprites;

        NSString *image = [images objectAtIndex:3];
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:image];
        sprite.position = ccp(AREA_A2_X2 - (i * 56), AREA_A3A5A4_Y);
        [self addChild:sprite];
        [movableSprites addObject:sprite];
```

So far so good.

Now I am trying to detect collisions among them. The user is able to move the sprites around, but I want the sprites to be blocked by one another.

So, when I am working on the translation of them I want it to happen there. By the way, is it the best place to go for a collision detection?

```
- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {
    if (selSprite) {
```

I intent to do the following in a loop:

```
    CGRect rect1 = [SpriteUtilities positionRect:selSprite];

    CGRect rect2 = [SpriteUtilities positionRect:EVERY_OTHER_SPRITE];

    if (!CGRectIsNull(CGRectIntersection(rect1, rect2))) {
        //handle collision
    }
```

The thing is... I didn't find a NSMutableArray method to retrieve the sprite object.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... after a few more reading I got into this:

```
CCSprite *toCollide;
for (int i = 0; i < [movableSprites count]; i++){

    toCollide = [movableSprites objectAtIndex:i];
...
```

Thanks anyway!! Hope it helps somebody else!

Comment: if you use the code of the question, next you are going to wonder why the array is empty !

Comment: you did not create the array object , like moveableSprites = [[NSMutableArray array] retain]; (retain if you dont use ARC, dont forget to release in dealloc).